# Mocking an Eloquent collection response from another mocked class

Tags: unit-testing, laravel-4, phpunit

I Have looked at many questions along the same line of thought here on stack overflow, and else where but unable to find a solution to this particular issue.

I'm fairly new to Unit Testing in general, so the mistake may be (hopefully) obvious to someone with more experience.

Here's the issue:

I have a ResourceController that injects a class into the constructor using Depedency Injection.

```
public function __construct(ResourceAPIInterface $api)
{

    $this->api = $api; 

}
```

When that API is called in the controller, the class that was injected does some business logic and returns an Eloquent Collection.

```
public function index($resource, $version)
{
    $input = Input::all();
    //Populate Data
    $data = $this->api->fetchAll($input);


    //Format response
    if($data->isEmpty()){
        //Format response
        $response = Response::make(" ", 204);
           }else {
        //Format response
        $response = Response::make($data, 200);
           }

    //Set content-type in header
    $response->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    $response->header('Cache-Control', 'max-age=3600');
    return $response;
}
```

As you can see from the code above, I need the response to be an eloquent response so i can test to see if it's empty. The method FetchAll literally just returns a Eloquent collation of all records in the table. When I do the test, i'm able to mock the API without issue. However when i'm mocking the response, i really want the response to be an eloquent collection, and having difficulty getting that to work. Here's an example of the test:

```
            $course = Mockery::mock(new API\Entity\v1\Test);
    $this->mock->shouldReceive('fetchAll')->once()->andReturn($course->all());
    $this->mock->shouldReceive('name')->once()->andReturn('Course');

    // Act... 
    $response = $this->action('GET', 'ResourceController@show'); 

    // Assert... 
    $this->assertResponseOk();
```

The above works, but when i want to do the same test against the show method and mock the eloquent response for ->first() I'm getting errors.

```
  1) ResourceControllerTest::testshow
   BadMethodCallException: Method Mockery_1_API_Entity_v1_Test_API_Entity_v1_Test::first() does not exist on this mock object
```

I've tried to test the model by doing:

```
        $course = Mockery::mock('Eloquent', 'API\Entity\v1\Test');
           $response = $course->mock->shouldReceive('find')->with(1)->once()->andReturn((object)array('id'=>1, 'name'=>'Widget-name','description'=>'Widget description'));
```

However when I run that in the Test I get the following error:

```
  1) ResourceControllerTest::testIndex
  BadMethodCallException: Method Mockery_1_API_Entity_v1_Test::getAttribute() does not exist on this mock object
```

Any Ideas on how to resolve this issue? Also, if there's a better way to test if the eloquent collection is empty that might resolve some of the complexity that I'm running into is also welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out how to make this work:

```
public function testIndex($resource="course", $version="v1")
{
    // Arrange... 
    $course = Mockery::mock('Eloquent', 'API\Entity\v1\Page')->makePartial();
    $course->shouldReceive('isEmpty')->once()->andReturn(false);
    $course->shouldReceive('all')->once()->andReturn($course);
    $this->mock->shouldReceive('fetchAll')->once()->andReturn($course->all());

    $this->mock->shouldReceive('name')->once()->andReturn('Course');

    // Act... 
    $response = $this->action('GET', 'ResourceController@index'); 

    // Assert... 
    $this->assertResponseOk(); 


}
```

I was able to do the PartialMock to get around the getAttribute() Error. Once I did that, I started getting the error:

```
Call to undefined method stdClass::isEmpty()
```

So I decided to mock that as well, and pass the whole mocked object into the expected response for the all command.

Then in the mock for the API class $this->mock-> i had it return The mocked eloquent collection with the ->all() method.

This is also working for the other test i had for find($id). That one however didn't require an isEmpty() check so was easier to mock.